# Notification icons are cut in half in SystemUI with status bar padding (Android Pie)

Tags: android, user-interface, build

I'm trying to solve a problem with SystemUI's dimens.xml on my Pie-based ROM (it happens on stock as well).

Currently, when a notification arrives, it looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztYzp.jpg) (the notification icon is basically cropped from the left side).

The only thing that solves it is reducing `rounded_corner_content_padding` and `status_bar_padding_start` in SystemUI's dimens.xml. However, this also pushes the status bar edges way too close to the screen borders, which doesn't look pretty.

Is it possible to get rid of this part of the notification altogether? It seems redundant considering there are heads-up notifications already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also stumped upon this problem recently. After digging through the frameworks/base source code, I believe that it is a bug in the AOSP upstream, that `rounded_corner_content_padding` is not accounted for in `HeadsUpStatusBarView`, causing the layout function to behave incorrectly. I've tried to fix this and submitted a patch to AOSP,

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/964275

where you can find a more detailed description and download the patch to apply to your own ROM.

Of course, I am not sure whether this is really a bug in AOSP or just a problem on my side -- this has to be reviewed by the AOSP development team.